# Why passing an iterator to foreach loop?

Tags: r, foreach, iterator

I didn't understand what the advantage is, especially in terms of performance, in passing an iterator rather than a vector or a list in a `foreach::foreach` loop. Reading the vignettes, it is understood that one of the advantages is that an iterator

> maintains information about its state, in particular its current index.

the Writing Custom Iterators vignette states:

> Iterators can also be used to reduce the total memory that is needed
> at any one time.

and

> Iterators are particularly useful in parallel computing since they
> facilitate splitting a problem into smaller pieces that can then be
> executed in parallel

but what is the main advantage in terms of e.g., computational time elapsed in a parallel operation?
Why should I prefer using an iterator in `foreach`, both for `%do%` and `%dopar%`?

**EDIT**
I know SO is not the best place to ask such broad questions despite mine being actually a theoretical one. However, here I provide an example of using `foreach` for a typical task of mine:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
#register an implicit cluster
registerDoParallel(parallel::detectCores()-1)

#get the path of some files in getwd()(e.g., csv, txt, etc.)
paths->list.files(full.name=T)

foreach(i = paths) %dopar% {
  df->read.csv(i)
  #do something here that could take up to several minutes
  write.csv(df,newpath)
}
stopImplicitCluster()
```

what would be the difference with this code:

```
foreach(i = iter(paths)) %dopar% {
      df->read.csv(i)
      #do something here that could take up to several minutes
      write.csv(df,newpath)
    }
```

I know the question is still broad and theoretical, but @MrFlick mentioned that some workflows do not benefit from iterators. Is this example one of this workflow?

Comment: It's hard to answer such a broad, theoretical question. Is there a specific workflow you are trying? Not all workflows will benefit from iterators, but if you want to "reduce the total memory" used or "split the problem into smaller pieces", those are the main advantages of iterators as the docs already state. Not sure what's unclear about those statements. Perhaps if you provide a more practical example it would be easier to illustrate differences.

Comment: There would be no practical difference if `paths` is a existing vector compared with `iter(paths)`. The big differences come when then iterator does not have all the values pre-compiled and instead just returns the next value in a sequence on demand. If you use `x <- iterators::icount(1000000)` it doesn't create a vector with a million elements, it creates an iterator that only ever returns one number at a time. It takes up much less memory.